# Attempt to get AngularJS to work in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsfiddle

I'm following along an online tutorial, and attempting to get **angularjs** to work on **jsfiddle**. i'm not very familiar with jsfiddle and am having a hard time getting the javascript and html to work together due to (i think) the jsfiddle settings.

here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/russellelbert/yh4c1hoe/

**HTML:**

```
<h1>{{"hiking..."}}</h1>
    <div ng-controller="HikeController as hike">
    <h1> {{hike.trail.name}}  </h1>
    <h1> {{hike.trail.miles}} </h1>
    <h1> {{"keep going"}}     </h1>
</div>    
<h1>{{"done"}}</h1>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('rew', []);
    app.controller('HikeController', function(){
        this.trail = hike;
    });
    var hike = {
        name: 'Colchuck Lake',
        miles: 4.5,
    }
})();
```

i have the framework and extensions set to:

- No-Library (pure JS)
- No wrap - in <body>

and the fiddle options set to:

- body tag: <body ng-app="rew">

but only the first H1 seems to be working. output is such:

```
    hiking...
    {{hike.trail.name}}
    {{hike.trail.miles}}
    {{"keep going"}}
    {{"done"}}
```

can anyone see what i am doing wrong? i'd like to keep the structure of the javascript as similar as it is to the code shown so i can follow along with the tutorial - my assumption is that something is wrong in the jsfiddle settings.

thanks for your help!

Comment: just set framework to angular, you were using version 1.01 which is really old  http://jsfiddle.net/yh4c1hoe/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using old version of angular. Updated the version. Everything else was fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/yh4c1hoe/1/

```
No Code changes.
```

Comment: that's it, thanks!! FYI for others: updated the version to AngularJS 1.2.1 under 'Framework & Extensions', then removed angularjs from the 'External Resources' section - see example from @core in the above answer.